# Air iOS,Flash Pro, external mp3 won't be played

Tags: ios, flash, audio, air, mp3

My flash app has the following code. The sound is played when locally testing but it's not played when published on iOS.

The mp3 file is inside components/sound directory and the directory is included via Air iOS3.6 publish setting in Adobe Flash cs6 professional.

I did some testing and while the mp3 file and the directory exists(tested with File.exists) in iOS, sound.bytesLoaded shows 0 value. When testing locally, it shows actual file size.

Can anyone help me with this?

```
var path= File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("components/sound/click.mp3").nativePath;
var sound = new Sound(new URLRequest(path));
sound.play();
```

[Edit]

It worked when I simply replaced new URLRequest(path) to new URLRequest("components/sound/click.mp3").

However, I would still appreciate if someone could explain why the former one(nativePath) didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading [this thread on Adobe Community forums](http://forums.adobe.com/message/4857732) about loading external sounds on iOS, your code seems OK, the only suspicious thing I see is that you should begin the file path with "/", like:

```
var path= File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("/components/sound/click.mp3").nativePath;
```

Hope this helps!